# jQuery modal and overlay - floats in modal div messing up display

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

Please visit my temp site at http://idataonline.idataresearch.com/index.php and click the member login at the top right.  I need to know what's going on with my css with regard to how the modal login box and overlay are displaying out of wack. The overlay shows up way down the page and doesn't have a background color.  The overlay should show to darken the page and be clickable to close the modal.  It is currently clickable, but you have to scroll way down to where it actually is to click it ...

Comment: no it's not, please see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to your div class "ui-widget-overlay"

```
 <style type="text/css">
    width: 1343px;
    height: 1264px;
    z-index: 1001;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
 </style>
```

Comment: thankyou, that was it.  It's because I'm missing the jqueryui css

Answer (score 0):

its coming as desired only i guess?please elaborate your problem and if possible show some code.One thing i noticed your modal is larger in dimension than the screen displaying hence your getting more scroll at right

Comment: are using any plugin for this modal display..if not i will suggest you using Block ui-http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: i just want to use the native jQueryUI modal.  I've used it in another spot in the same way and it worked great ...